PDFBox to simplify PDF's graphics commands (e.g. removing q if it's not needed)
I've noticed that, on Preview, if I remove pages, the graphics commands (e.g. q, Tm, re) seems to be simplified.
I wonder if there's a similar way to achieve that in PDFBox.
For context, I am trying to match 2 PDF pages using their checksums. What I've found is that, in the 2 original PDF docs, the checksums of the two pages that are supposed to match don't match. However, if I open the 2 PDF pages in Preview (Mac) and delete every other page and save them back, then the checksums of the two pages match.
Please let me know if any clarification is needed. Thank you!


The decision whether some instructions are needed or not, is more of less easy. Thus, can you share your 2 pages both in their original form and in their manipulated form to check what kinds of simplifications you are after? Otherwise, please specify exactly those simplifications.

That being said, even after such a simplification two pages looking alike won't necessarily have the same hash. Do you have any reason to believe that they will in your case? Are they identically created but manipulated in some not very destructiv way?

As an example, I can see the 2 pages (called A and B in 2 different docs) that look the same. One start with q. The other isn't. If I understand correctly, q simply pushes the stack, so we can push it many times and it wouldn't matter to the drawing.
Then, if I open these 2 docs in Preview (mac), delete an unrelated page, and saves it, the drawing commands of A and B becomes identical. Preview (mac) seems to simplifies or canonicalize the drawing commands. I'd like to understand whether this is a common algorithm or Preview (mac) has a special algo to do this.

Honestly, this is a fool's errand.  The checksum is useless.  There are an infinite number of ways to encode a page in Postscript that all produce exactly the same output.

"As an example, I can see the 2 pages..." - as long as you don't share those example files here (before and after preview changed them), we can only guess. Nonetheless, IMO it is unlikely that the preview normalization gives rise to identical hash value except for streams that were very similar internally (not merely in output) to begin with. Or, of course, the actual page content may be moved to a form XObject and the page content only contains the drawing of that XObject. That could make the hash of all page content streams equal .. ;)

Thank you both for your perspectives. I'll find a different way to tackle this problem since it doesn't seem like there's such a thing as a standard algorithm to make graphics commands "canonical".
